# Adding custom code to theme regions

Tags: drupal

I've created a region in my theme's .info file, and added the region variable to `page.tpl.php`. If I want to add some code to this region, how do I do it?

Comment: In the future, please take a few minutes to proof-read what you write. It goes a long way in being able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you use the region name you declared in your info file as a variable in your template files.

Long answer: here is an excellent video on how to do theming.
The whole region system is explained in this video, and a lot more.

http://acquia.com/community/resources/acquia-tv/tips-and-tricks-drupal-theming-90-minute-tutorial

Greetz,
J.