# Design a site in drupal: General Overview

Tags: drupal-6

I am new in Drupal Development. I want to make a site in Drupal which contains 5, 6 pages including a home page. They all are different in sense of theme and structure. I am strugling with different structure for each page. Which of the modules should I use? What should be the proper way to start? Which things should I keep in mind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Home page:

- You can use the front page module to customize your home page: http://drupal.org/project/front
- You can use itweak login to customize login: http://drupal.org/project/itweak_login

General:

Look at templating end theming drupal as suggested in this post: [Adding custom code to theme regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409329/adding-custom-code-to-theme-regions/4409433#4409433)
The post also contains a very useful link on how to get stated with theming.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,
but what about all pages have different structure(Regions)? Should they be handled through templating you mentioned?

Comment: I think your problem is summarized on the following pages:

Different layouts for different pages -- how?
http://drupal.org/node/244188 and Using different page templates depending on the current path http://drupal.org/node/104316

Answer (score 0):

The [Panels module](http://drupal.org/project/panels) allows you to create pages with different structures.